# CRM 2016 OnPremise set/edit ModifiedOn date

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is it supported to set/edit the attribute ModifiedOn date programmatically (plugin, customized workflow or webservice)?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible and not supported. Only the CreatedOn date can be overridden by writing to the `overriddencreatedon` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in supported way but if you're using On-Premises you can use direct SQL updates to modify modifiedon field but of course it is not supported.